# WPF Application deployment XAML parsing errors - .NET Framework version issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.0

I created a new WPF application with target framework as .NET Framework 3.0. I developed WPF windows some of which used `DropShadowBitMapEffect` for Border tag:

```
<Border CornerRadius="20" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFABE3E4" Background="#FFE6F7FF">
     <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="Gray" ShadowDepth="2" Direction="320" />
     </Border.Effect>
</Border>
```

The development environment had .NET framework versions 4.0, 3.5 SP1, 3.0 and 2.0 installed and everything worked fine. When I deploy it to a new system, I get the following XAML parse exception:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Cannot find DependencyProperty or PropertyInfo for property named 'Effect'. Property names are case sensitive.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.Border' in markup file ...
```

The deployment system contains .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 (no service packs for 3.5) on Windows XP. Now, is this expected? I chose the target framework as 3.0 right from the start and I was always able to compile the application. If its the case, shouldn't my Application run on any system with .NET framework 3.0 installed? Why is it giving a parse exception in this case?

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Links already referenced (the references are all for .NET framework 3.5. I am looking for something specific to 3.0):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xwebsupport/archive/2010/01/06/cannot-find-dependencyproperty-or-propertyinfo-property-error-during-xweb3-setup.aspx

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535637/net-3-5-sp1-not-working-on-vista-enterprise-cannot-find-dependencyproperty-or-propertyinfo-for-property-named-effect

Answer (score 0):

Effect and the DropShadowEffect was added in WPF 3.5

Comment: Ummm.. This says that it is available in .NET 3.0. I am using the bitmap effect and not the media effect which was introduced in 3.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753350%28v=VS.85%29.aspx    Nevertheless if it was not available in .NET 3.0 why would Visual Studio allow me to use the class when I have targeted the application for .NET 3.0?